# Extending classes in Scala - newbie inquiry

Tags: scala

I have the following Scala classes:

```
class ClassA (x2: Int, y2: Int) {
  var x = x2
  var y = y2
}


class ClassB (x2: Int, y2: Int, z2: Int) extends ClassA (x2, y2) {
  var z = z2
}
```

If the classes are used as value objects and don't have any methods, is there a point of extending ClassB with ClassA? I need to define all the fields in ClassB anyways.

Comment: Why would you need to define the fields in class B anyway?

Comment: Depends if you have code that works on `ClassA` objects and you want it to work on instances of different subclasses of `ClassA`. Otherwise I'd just `case class ClassB(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)`.

Comment: Consider using `val`s and a trait: `trait C{val x:Int; val y:Int}`. Then `case class ClassA(x:Int, y:Int) extends C` and `case class classB(x:Int, y:Int, z:Int) extends C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, with no methods you are basically not using polymorphism, so the value of inheritance is greatly diminished. For strict value objects use [case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) like this:

```
case class ClassA(x:Int, y:Int)
case class ClassB(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)
```

Thad does the trick and also now your classes have default `copy`, `equals`, `hash` and `apply` operations. Aternatively, if you are dealing with lots of variables, you can attempt composition:

```
case class ClassB(a: ClassA, z2: Int)
```

Or, if you can dispense with the constructors and are willing to use default values, you could avoid redefining stuff and use traits:

```
trait TraitA {
   var x = 0
   var y = 0
}

trait TraitB extends TraitA {
   var z = 0
}
```

Objectively, it depends on what you end up doing with these. In my experience, good Object-Oriented design usually ends up having methods. To group data and the methods that operate over it into a single cohesive cblack box is the whole idea. But for functional programmng I've ended up using case classes.

Comment: The problem with the traits approach is that you can't instantiate a trait, so you'd need to create a class that extends the trait anyway.

Comment: You certainly can, albeit yes, you create an annonymous class. Try `val x = new TraitB {}`

Answer (score 1):

for the first thing, if your real example is not more complicated than what you presented you could do this:

```
class ClassA (var x: Int, var y: Int)
class ClassB (x: Int, y: Int, var z: Int) extends ClassA(x, y)
```

which is less verbose equivalent but, you still have a good amount of boilerplate.

To answer the question whether you should use inheritance you should answer another question: is sentence "object of class `ClassB` IS also an object of class `ClassA`" true, does it adhere to to LSP. If you would use `ClassB` where `ClassA` is needed then I think inheritance is a valid decision.

Alternatively you could go with composition, letting `ClassB` contain instance of `ClassA`, whatever seems more logical.

I also would like to encourage you to use immutable classes, if you decide that your classes are unrelated or you use composition. You will get a free `copy` method that will allow you to easly "modify" your object, and a lot more.